# Does it violate the MVC pattern's separation of concerns if a model class contains a static method whose parameters are instances of a View object?

Tags: java, android, model-view-controller, separation-of-concerns

```
public static Intent prepare( EditText to, EditText cc, EditText subject, EditText content ){

Intent preparedIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_SEND );
preparedIntent.setType( "plain/text" );
preparedIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[ ] 
{ 

    to.getText().toString( )

});
preparedIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[ ]
{

cc.getText( ).toString( )

});
preparedIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,subject.getText().toString());

preparedIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,content.getText().toString());

return preparedIntent;}
```

### Does it violate the MVC pattern's separation of concerns if a model class contains a static method whose parameters are instances of a View object?

I'm trying to research whether it is **not** a **proper** implementation of the ***MVC pattern's separation of concerns*** if I choose to provide a static helper method in my Email.java class  that is used for *returning an instance of an intent* **within** the scope of the email client's activity class. The **reasons** for me questioning this design decision is that even though an intent is **not** an instance of **View** however I am *passing* objects that **are** instances of **View** objects within the scope of the Email.java (model) class.

Therefore, assuming I am not conforming to the MVC pattern, ***would changing the parameter types to **String** and having each instance of View return an object of type string by calling its*** viewObject.getText().toString() ***within the parameter construct everytime I wish to invoke the Email.prepare( .....) method then allow for conformity to the MVC pattern by utilizing proper separation of concerns?***

[**Here is a link**](https://github.com/ChristopherBasinger/BITS-J-Android-Social_Manager/tree/master/Social_Manager/src) to the code if it better helps in possibly forming an answer. The two classes in question are the EmailActivity.java file in the activities package and the Email.java file in the models package.

Thank you for any input by the way ahead of time. I was just curious about this. It is obviously not a major issue and more minor but I am trying to learn design patters. I know the general answer is "well you're the designer!".

Comment: Is this actually affecting your code at all, or is it just a philosophical question? I think it's mostly just splitting hairs. You might consider pulling the Strings out first and doing some validation on them, in case something invalid should show something to the user in the UI (which seems very **VIEW**), but that might not be necessary in your use case.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a philosophical question. I'm really trying to see if I am following Android coding standards in terms of software engineering in the "industry". I can do work arounds for anything I want if it is just my code but I want to know if it would be considered to violate separation of concerns in regards to the MVC pattern.

Comment: Working for a large internet company building one of their Android apps, I can tell you that the difference between the two methods you describe are pretty small compared to other design decisions that go on in a project. This is something you can change in 3 minutes if you later decide the other approach is better. Android already isn't completely MVC as a platform.

Comment: You need to close this question if it's been "answered" either because you aren't worried about it or because you understand better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code violates a couple of accepted coding practices but not necessarily MVC.  Here is how I would re-factor it so that it is [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and follows [LoD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

```
public static Intent prepare( String to, String cc, String subject, String content, String messageType )
{

    if (messageType==null){ messageType = "plain/text"; }

    Intent preparedIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_SEND );
    preparedIntent.setType( messageType );

    if (to!=null) {
        preparedIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[ ] 
        { 
            to
        });
    }

    if (cc!=null) {
        preparedIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[ ]
        {
            cc
        });
    }
    preparedIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

    preparedIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);

    return preparedIntent;
}
```

This way, you don't have to reference a specific type of control (`EditText`) and you can re-use this static method anywhere you need to create an email `Intent`

Comment: Hey thank you. That actually helped me to begin to wrap my head around code re-usage in Android. I understand how to do it in Java but once I threw in the Android SDK with the View objects I began to notice my code was very messy whenever I got into any of my Activity classes. Much appreciated! I would give you ups for going out of your way and refactoring it for me but unfortunately no can do.